# How to convert a for-loop to lapply function for parallel testing purposes?

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply

I've been studying the advantages/disadvantages of for-loops versus versus the `apply()` family of functions and the answer isn't clear cut (`apply()` always faster than for-loops may not be true, depending on circumstances). So I want to test the various options against my actual data.

Below is a for-loop which looks pretty straightforward to me, but I'm unsure of how to replace it with `lapply()`. I assume `lapply()` is correct since the for-loop produces a list object.

The actual data I need to run this analysis against is a data frame containing 2.5 million rows, 30+ columns, so I'd like to run speed tests against the various options.

Any explanation would be most helpful. The examples I found online are light on explanations or the for-loops examples overly-complex, and I hope to learn to use `apply()` family functions well as they seem very useful and simpler to read than for-loops.

Here's the simplified for-loop code, with example data frame, which runs correctly for example purposes:

```
# Set up data frame to perform migration analysis on:
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

# Function to set-up base table:
setTable <- function(data){
  df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=length(unique(data$Flags)), nrow=length(unique(data$Flags))))
  row.names(df) <- unique(data$Flags)
  names(df) <- unique(data$Flags)
  return(df)
}

# Function to complete migration table with for-loop:
migration <- function(data, from=1, to=3){
  df <- setTable(data)
  for (i in unique(data$ID)){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(df) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(df) == id_to)
    df[row, column] <- ifelse(is.na(df[row, column]), 1, df[row, column] + 1)
  }
  return(df)
}

# Now to run the function:
test1 <- migration(data, from=1, to=3)
```

Comment: Is this a network problem? It looks like you have some kind of migration events that could be represented by a network structure. If that is the case the `igraph` package most likely has helpful functions for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** wrapped in a function allowing to specify from & to:

```
library(data.table)

DF <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9),
  Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
)

migration <- function(DT, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(DT)
  unique_flags <- unique(DT$Flags)
  all_flags <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_flag = unique_flags, to_flag = unique_flags)))
  
  dcast(DT[, .(from_flag = Flags[Period == from], to_flag = Flags[Period == to]), by = ID][
    ,.N, c("from_flag", "to_flag")][
      all_flags, on = c("from_flag", "to_flag")], to_flag ~ from_flag, value.var = "N")
}

migration(DF, 1, 3)
```

---

When it comes to [speed](https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/) in R, you can almost always count on library([data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)):

```
library(data.table)

DT <- setDT(data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9),
  Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
))

unique_flags <- unique(DT$Flags)
all_flags <- setDT(expand.grid(list(first_flag = unique_flags, last_flag = unique_flags)))

resultDT <- dcast(DT[, .(first_flag = first(Flags), last_flag = last(Flags)), by = ID][
  ,.N, c("first_flag", "last_flag")][
    all_flags, on = c("first_flag", "last_flag")], last_flag ~ first_flag, value.var = "N")

print(resultDT)
```

---

Step by step:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- setDT(data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9),
  Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
))

unique_flags <- unique(DT$Flags)
all_flags <- setDT(expand.grid(list(first_flag = unique_flags, last_flag = unique_flags)))

resultDT <- DT[, .(first_flag = first(Flags), last_flag = last(Flags)), by = ID] # find relevant flags
resultDT <- resultDT[,.N, c("first_flag", "last_flag")] # count transitions
resultDT <- resultDT[all_flags, on = c("first_flag", "last_flag")] # merge all combinations
resultDT <- dcast(resultDT, last_flag ~ first_flag, value.var = "N") # dcast
print(resultDT)
```

---

Regarding `lapply` you can do (I'd prefer `data.table`):

```
# Set up data frame to perform migration analysis on:
input_data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    Flags = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

# Function to set-up base table:
setTable <- function(data){
  DF <- data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol=length(unique(data$Flags)), nrow=length(unique(data$Flags))))
  row.names(DF) <- unique(data$Flags)
  names(DF) <- unique(data$Flags)
  return(DF)
}

# Function to complete migration table with for-loop:
migration <- function(data, from=1, to=3){
  DF <- setTable(data)
  lapply(seq_along(unique(data$ID)), function(i){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(DF) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(DF) == id_to)
    DF[row, column] <<- ifelse(is.na(DF[row, column]), 1, DF[row, column] + 1)
  })
  return(DF)
}

# Now to run the function:
test1 <- migration(input_data, from=1, to=3)
```

Comment: Hi ismirsehregal, I'm trying to modify your data.table suggestion to reflect user inputs for period transition from/to. You'll see in the OP a specified migration from period 1 to period 3. In the actual data this is used for, the user would usually not specify a "to" period of the last period in the data set. I've been trying to modify the above to reflect user-specified periods of from/to, no luck yet. Do you know of the easiest way to do this? Btw I've benchmarked the for-loop and lapply() options against 500k rows of data, way too slow!! Though lapply() is a bit faster than for-loop.

Comment: How should the user specified "to" value be detected? Is there a marker or something?

Comment: In the OP, there is a function defined as migration <- function(data, from=1, to=3)... The from/to specifications look to the data$Period column of the data frame

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 ok I think I understand - please see if my edit meets your expectations.

Comment: Yes!! Many thanks! I'll study data.table package and speed test it. I wonder how it compares with base R table(), though I think table() will only work for transition counts and not transition values

Comment: OK and the winner is...data.table!! You're right ismirsehregal, data.table is fast. To run this against 500k rows, for-loop and lapply took over 2 minutes each; data.table took only .06 seconds

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 learning data.table really pays off. I use it in all my scripts. Please see their [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/). I just made a small modification to the data.table code which is relevant only if the period column isn't sorted.