# Why does this lapply() function applied to a dataframe not produce the same results as its for-loop equivalent?

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

In the below reproducible code, the custom `balTransit()` function **correctly** populates a values transition table using a for-loop, while the custom `balTransit_1()` function is supposed to do the same using `lapply()` but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong in my implementation of `lapply()`? Run the code and you'll see results of:

**balTransit** (correct results):

```
> test
   X1 X0 X2
X1  0  0  3
X0  0 50  0
X2  5  0  0
```

**balTransit_1** (incorrect, all 0's):

```
> test_1
   X1 X0 X2
X1  0  0  0
X0  0  0  0
X2  0  0  0
```

Enhanced explanation:

My main objective here is to learn how to use the `apply()` family of functions, for their perceived benefits. I’ve been going through simple tutorials.  A secondary objective is the generation of a transition matrix from a base data frame. Once I figure this out with `lapply()` (or another `apply()` function that is most suitable), I’m going to run the various options (`for-loop()`, `data.table()`, `lapply()`, etc.) against the actual data set of 2.5m rows for speed testing.

What I’m doing is creating a transition matrix (technically here a data frame) showing the flow of values (balances) from one “Flags” category to another “Flags” category, over the periods specified by the user. So, in my “for-loop” reproducible example which works correctly, the user has specified a “From” period of 1 and a “To” period of 3. The transition matrix is then generated as shown in the image now posted at the bottom.

A related post yesterday, [How to convert a for-loop to lapply function for parallel testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368822/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-to-lapply-function-for-parallel-testing-purposes), addresses this issue for transition counts. This post addresses transition values.

Reproducible code:

```
# Set up data frame:
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 50, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    Flags = c("X1","X0","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X1")
  )

# Function to set-up base transition table:
transMat <- function(data){
  DF <- data.frame(matrix(0, ncol=length(unique(data$Flags)), nrow=length(unique(data$Flags))))
  row.names(DF) <- unique(data$Flags)
  names(DF) <- unique(data$Flags)
  return(DF)
}

# Function to populate cells of transition table, using for-loop:
balTransit <- function(data, from=1, to=3){
  DF <- transMat(data)
  for (i in unique(data$ID)){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(DF) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(DF) == id_to)
    
    val <- (data$Values[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    DF[row, column] <- val + DF[row,column]
  }
  return(DF)
}

# Function to populate cells of transition table, using lapply:
balTransit_1 <- function(data, from=1, to=3){
  DF_1 <- transMat(data)
  lapply(seq_along(unique(data$ID)), function(i){
    id_from <- as.character(data$Flags[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    id_to <- as.character(data$Flags[data$ID == i & data$Period == to])
    column <- which(names(DF_1) == id_from)
    row <- which(row.names(DF_1) == id_to)
    val <- (data$Values[(data$ID == i & data$Period == from)])
    DF_1[row, column] <- DF_1[row, column] + val
  })
  return(DF_1)
}

# Run the 2 functions:
test <- balTransit(data,1,3)
test

test_1 <- balTransit_1(data,1,3)
test_1
```

[image]

Comment: You are misusing `lapply` because you don't assign its return value to an object.  All changes made within the anonymous function you define are lost as soon as the function returns.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to `lapply` here? You seem to be trying to use `lapply` with a function that has side effects which really isn't what it's for. Changes made in the body of the function used during `lapply` are local to that function and not modified in the enclosing environment. Proper functions should be side-effect free and themselves should return new, updated values

Comment: I agree with @MrFlick.  There is almost certainly a simpler/better/more efficient way of doing what you're trying to do.  But I can't figure it out from your code.  If you can define how the entries in your output are calculated from the input, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: OK I just posted a more detailed explanation with image. Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to use `lapply` due to performance considerations, right? Please see my `data.table` approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your lapply code work just replace `<-` with `<<-`:

```
DF_1[row, column] <<- DF_1[row, column] + val
```

Please see `?assignOps` for more info.

However, again I wouldn't recommend `lapply` in this case (`<<-` should be avoided in general)

Here is a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- setDT(data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Values = c(5, 10, 15, 50, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
  Flags = c("X1","X0","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X1")
))

unique_flags <- unique(DT$Flags)
all_flags <- setDT(expand.grid(list(first_flag = unique_flags, last_flag = unique_flags)))

resultDT <- dcast(
  data = DT[, .(first_flag = first(Flags), last_flag = last(Flags), first_value = first(Values)), by = ID][
  all_flags, on = c("first_flag", "last_flag")],
  last_flag ~ first_flag,
  fun.aggregate = sum,
  value.var = "first_value"
  )

for (col_i in seq_len(ncol(resultDT))){
  set(resultDT, which(is.na(resultDT[[col_i]])), col_i, 0)
}
print(resultDT)
```

---

Result:

```
   last_flag X0 X1 X2
1:        X0 50  0  0
2:        X1  0  0  3
3:        X2  0  5  0
```

---

```
# step by step ------------------------------------------------------------
library(data.table)

DT <- setDT(data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4),
  Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
  Values = c(5, 10, 15, 50, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 9),
  Flags = c("X1","X0","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X1", "X2","X1","X1")
))

unique_flags <- unique(DT$Flags)
all_flags <- setDT(expand.grid(list(first_flag = unique_flags, last_flag = unique_flags)))

resultDT <- DT[, .(first_flag = first(Flags), last_flag = last(Flags), first_value = first(Values)), by = ID] # find relevant flags
resultDT <- resultDT[all_flags, on = c("first_flag", "last_flag")] # merge all combinations
resultDT <- dcast(resultDT, last_flag ~ first_flag, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "first_value") # dcast
for (col_i in seq_len(ncol(resultDT))){
  set(resultDT, which(is.na(resultDT[[col_i]])), col_i, 0)
}
print(resultDT)
```