# How to expand transition table to include all possible combinations, even those unused combinations?

Tags: r, matrix, datatable, markov-chains

I'm trying out the `table()` function in R for running transition matrices, and so far I'm finding it easy to use and very quick compared to other options I've been playing with such as for-loops and `lapply()`.

However I'd like to expand the output table to include all possible combinations even if they don't manifest in the data, populating those "unused" fields with 0's. Is there a quick/easy way to do this?

When I run the following example data frame through the `table()` function, both as shown below:

```
  ID Period Balance Flags
1 10      1       5   X00
2 10      2      10   X01
3 10      3      15   X00
4 11      1       0   X01
5 11      2       2   X02
6 11      3       4   X02
7 15      1       3   X02
8 15      2       6   X01
9 15      3       2   X00

dataTest <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(10,10,10,11,11,11,15,15,15),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Balance = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 2),
    Flags = c("X00","X01","X00","X01","X02","X02","X02","X01","X00")
  )

table(dataTest[dataTest$Period == 3,]$Flags, dataTest[dataTest$Period == 1,]$Flags)
```

I get the following results (which is correct):

```
      X00 X01 X02
  X00   1   0   1
  X02   0   1   0
```

However I would like to expand those results to include the unused combinations, so it looks like this:

```
      X00 X01 X02
  X00   1   0   1
  X01   0   0   0
  X02   0   1   0
```

This is a transition table, showing along the columns the state the elements started in (in Period = 1 per this example user input) and showing along the rows the state the elements ended in (in Period = 3 per this example user input).

Comment: I thought there were parameters described in the help page for ‘table’ that would let you create columns and rows for unused levels in factor classed vectors.

Comment: I did look at the help page before posting, tried "useNA = c("no", "ifany", "always")" with no luck. I'll keep looking through the materials in any case.

Comment: Btw. you already received an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71380841/9841389) indirectly. See the join on `all_flags`. data.table usually is much faster than dplyr / tidyr (@danloo's answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataTest <-
  data.frame(
    ID = c(10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Balance = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 2),
    Flags = c("X00", "X01", "X00", "X01", "X02", "X02", "X02", "X01", "X00")
  )

table(
  dataTest[dataTest$Period == 3, ]$Flags,
  dataTest[dataTest$Period == 1, ]$Flags
) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(
    Var1 = Var1 %>% factor(levels = unique(dataTest$Flags)),
    Var2 = Var2 %>% factor(levels = unique(dataTest$Flags)),
  ) %>%
  complete(Var1, Var2, fill = list(Freq = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var2, values_from = Freq)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Var1    X00   X01   X02
#>   <fct> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 X00       1     0     1
#> 2 X01       0     0     0
#> 3 X02       0     1     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>