# How to create a table that measures transitions of elements over calendar periods?

Tags: r, data.table, transition

I have a transition table generating function which calculates the transitions of the states of elements over time elapsed since the element first appears ("Period_1" in example data frame below), output and code as shown immediately below:

```
library(data.table)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Period_2 = c("2020-01","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04","2020-05","2020-06","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04"),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )

numTransit <- function(x, from=1, to=3){
  setDT(x)
  unique_state <- unique(x$State)
  all_states <- setDT(expand.grid(list(from_state = unique_state, to_state = unique_state)))
  dcast(x[, .(from_state = State[from], 
              to_state = State[to]), 
          by = ID]
        [,.N, c("from_state", "to_state")]
        [all_states,on = c("from_state", "to_state")], 
        to_state ~ from_state, value.var = "N"
  )
}

numTransit(data,1,3)
```

However, in the fuller code this is deployed in, I'm also trying to give the user the option to calculate the transitions over calendar periods instead ("Period_2" in the data frame), where the output would look like the below if the user wants to see transitions from month 2020-02 to 2020-04 (since only one element, ID = 3, existed from period 2020-02 to 2020-04, only one element is shown in the resulting transition table; and that element moved from state X2 to state X0 during that period):

```
> numTransit(data,"2020-02","2020-04")
   to_state X0 X1 X2
1:       X0 NA NA 1
2:       X1 NA NA NA
3:       X2 NA NA NA
```

Any ideas how to do this? I'm new to `data.table()` but am committed to it due to speed, as this function is run against millions of rows of data and it generates results in a fraction of a second. This post is a follow-on expansion of the post [How to convert a for-loop to lapply function for parallel testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71368822/how-to-convert-a-for-loop-to-lapply-function-for-parallel-testing-purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one alternative definition of your numTransit function.

(Updated: I moved the convert_to_matrix out of this function)

```
num_transit <- function(x,from,to,refvar="Period_2", return_matrix=T) {
  res <- x[get(refvar) %in% c(to,from), if(.N>1) .SD, by=ID, .SDcols = c(refvar, "State")]
  res <- res[, id:=1:.N, by=ID]
  res <- dcast(res, ID~id, value.var="State")[,.N, .(`1`,`2`)]
  setnames(res,c("from","to", "ct"))
  if(return_matrix) return(convert_transits_to_matrix(res, unique(x$State)))
  res
}

convert_transits_to_matrix <- function(transits,states) {
  m = matrix(NA, nrow=length(states), ncol=length(states), dimnames=list(states,states))
  m[as.matrix(transits[,.(to,from)])] <- transits$ct
  m = data.table(m)[,to_state:=rownames(m)]
  setcolorder(m,"to_state")
  return(m[])
}
```

Usage:

```
setDT(data)
num_transit(data, "2020-02", "2020-04")

   to_state    X0    X1    X2
     <char> <int> <int> <int>
1:       X0    NA    NA     1
2:       X1    NA    NA    NA
3:       X2    NA    NA    NA

num_transit(data, 1,3, refvar="Period_1")

   to_state    X0    X1    X2
     <char> <int> <int> <int>
1:       X0     1    NA     1
2:       X1    NA    NA    NA
3:       X2     1    NA    NA
```

Comment: Note that as of May/07/22 the dcast() in the above langtang solution stopped working. To resolve I changed it from dcast() to dcast.data.table(). Not sure why dcast() was rendered obsolete overnight.