# How to modify this data.table code to show balance transitions instead of event frequency transitions?

Tags: r, data.table, transition

I am using the below MWE code to generate a data frame of transition frequencies. It works well and fast. I am new to the `data.table` package and am having trouble converting it to show balance transitions.

To start, below is the example data frame, the transition frequency output when running the functions (using the two time measurements of "Period_1" and "Period_2"), and the underlying MWE code for those functions, all of which work as intended for transition frequencies:

```
> data
   ID Period_1 Period_2 Values State
1:  1        1  2020-01      5    X0
2:  1        2  2020-02     10    X1
3:  1        3  2020-03     15    X2
4:  2        1  2020-04      0    X0
5:  2        2  2020-05      2    X2
6:  2        3  2020-06      4    X0
7:  3        1  2020-02      3    X2
8:  3        2  2020-03      6    X1
9:  3        3  2020-04      9    X0

> setDT(data)
> num_transit(data, "2020-02", "2020-04",refvar="Period_2")
   to_state X0 X1 X2
1:       X0 NA NA  1
2:       X1 NA NA NA
3:       X2 NA NA NA

> setDT(data)
> num_transit(data, 1,3, refvar="Period_1")
   to_state X0 X1 X2
1:       X0  1 NA  1
2:       X1 NA NA NA
3:       X2  1 NA NA

library(data.table)
   
data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Period_2 = c("2020-01","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04","2020-05","2020-06","2020-02","2020-03","2020-04"),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9),
    State = c("X0","X1","X2","X0","X2","X0", "X2","X1","X0")
  )
    
num_transit <- function(x,from,to,refvar="Period_2", return_matrix=T) {
  res <- x[get(refvar) %in% c(to,from), if(.N>1) .SD, by=ID, .SDcols = c(refvar, "State")]
  res <- res[, id:=1:.N, by=ID]
  res <- dcast(res, ID~id, value.var="State")[,.N, .(`1`,`2`)]
  setnames(res,c("from","to", "ct"))
  if(return_matrix) return(convert_transits_to_matrix(res, unique(x$State)))
  res
}
    
convert_transits_to_matrix <- function(transits,states) {
  m = matrix(NA, nrow=length(states), ncol=length(states), dimnames=list(states,states))
  m[as.matrix(transits[,.(to,from)])] <- transits$ct
  m = data.table(m)[,to_state:=rownames(m)]
  setcolorder(m,"to_state")
  return(m[])
}
```

Here is where I need help. I am trying to modify the above (call it "val_transit") to show the transition of the "Values" TO the new state. So the output would look like this, using the `data` dataframe and running Period_2 transitions from 1 to 3 (or `val_transit(data, 1,3, refvar="Period_1")`):

```
   to_state X0 X1 X2
1:       X0  4 NA  9
2:       X1 NA NA NA
3:       X2 15 NA NA
```

Any suggestions for doing this? This is a follow-on to transition frequency post [How to create a table that measures transitions of elements over calendar periods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71508209/how-to-create-a-table-that-measures-transitions-of-elements-over-calendar-period)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, here is an update to the previous `num_transit` function. Notice the differences

1. `.SDcols` included both `State` and `Values` in the first line of the function
2. `value.vars` in the `dcast` call includes both `State` and `Value`
3. As a result of (2) above, I group explicitly over `State_1`,`State_2`, instead of `1` and `2`, and the summarizing action is to sum the `Values`
4. The `setnames` call is adjusted to return the final column as `Values` if `return_matrix=F`

```
val_transit <- function(x,from,to,refvar="Period_2", return_matrix=T) {
  res <- x[get(refvar) %in% c(to,from), if(.N>1) .SD, by=ID, .SDcols = c(refvar, "State", "Values")]
  res <- res[, id:=1:.N, by=ID]
  res <- dcast(res, ID~id, value.var=c("State", "Values"))[,.(Values=sum(Values_2,na.rm=T)), .(State_1, State_2)]
  setnames(res,c("from","to", "Values"))
  if(return_matrix) return(convert_transits_to_matrix(res, unique(x$State)))
  res
}
```

Notice below that I made a minor update to my `convert_transits_to_matrix` function, so that this helper function works with both `val_transit()` and `num_transit()`. The minor update is in the 2nd line, where I use `transits[[3]]`, so that it works regardless of the actual 3rd column name in `transits` object.

```
convert_transits_to_matrix <- function(transits,states) {
  m = matrix(NA, nrow=length(states), ncol=length(states), dimnames=list(states,states))
  m[as.matrix(transits[,.(to,from)])] <- transits[[3]]
  m = data.table(m)[,to_state:=rownames(m)]
  setcolorder(m,"to_state")
  return(m[])
}
```

Usage:

```
val_transit(data,"2020-02","2020-04", "Period_2")
   to_state    X0    X1    X2
     <char> <num> <num> <num>
1:       X0    NA    NA     9
2:       X1    NA    NA    NA
3:       X2    NA    NA    NA

val_transit(data,1,3, "Period_1")

   to_state    X0    X1    X2
     <char> <num> <num> <num>
1:       X0     4    NA     9
2:       X1    NA    NA    NA
3:       X2    15    NA    NA
```

Make sure your `data` is setDT(data) before feeding it to these functions.

Comment: THANK YOU and those explanations really help me understand!